# Do something when notification bar is selected

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How do I do something when the ios notification bar(or whatever it is called) is dropped down? I want to show my loading picture when the user checks the bar when in my app. Netflix does this (at least in my ipad) when you are in Netflix and you drop the notification bar down, the Netflix app changes so that it is the same picture as when it is loading(their logo on a red background that takes up the whole view) and when the notification bar hides, it goes right back to whatever you were looking at. I'm more familiar with android so forgive my bad ios vocab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can sense when the notification center is pulled down from the status bar.
However, you can simply react to the

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

method ([doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a)), in your AppDelegate. This method gets called the exact same moment you start pulling down the notification center, but it also gets called in other situations (for example, every time your app moves to background, or a SMS message comes in...).

If you need to differentiate the behavior from the - say - "background" case, you should note that when pulling down the notification center the `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method doesn't get called, while in the background case, it does.

Hope this can help!